# `Error: Columns `y`, `colour` must be 1d atomic vectors or lists`. I have no column `colour`

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecast

I am trying to create a simple ggplot with 3 `geom_line`s to show normal, 5 and 10 year moving averages. My dataframe is `temp` with column being `AverageTemperature`. However I cannot understand the following errors:

`Error: Columns 'y', 'colour' must be 1d atomic vectors or lists`,

`Error: 'mapping' must be created by 'aes()'`

I have no column called y or colour and all my mapping. Other answers do not seem to explain the reason behind the errors. My code is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
ma <- ma(temp$AverageTemperature, order = 5)
ma2 <- ma(temp$AverageTemperature, order = 10)

ggplot(temp, x= dt) + 
    geom_line(temp, aes(y = AverageTemperature, size = 1.5)) + scale_y_log10() + xlim(1870, 2000) +
    geom_line(temp, aes(y = ma, color = ma, size = 1.5)) +  
    geom_line(temp, aes(y = ma2, color = ma, size = 1.5)) `
```

My required result would look like the following graph:

https://www.datascience.com/hs-fs/hubfs/learn-data-science-forecasting-with-ARIMA-chart-3.png?width=1900&height=713&name=learn-data-science-forecasting-with-ARIMA-chart-3.png

Sample data using `dput`:

`structure(list(dt = c(1743L, 1744L, 1745L, 1750L, 1751L, 1752L ), AverageTemperatureUncertainty = c(3.1304125, 3.0976671875, 3.00175, 3.13747272727273, 3.09229285714285, 3.06561458333333 )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Could someone explain what the errors are please?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Once you find that you're calling several `geom_line`, it might be time to reshape your data. Please provide sample data using `dput`. You need to make an `aes`  in line 1 of the ggplot.

Comment: `structure(list(dt = c(1743L, 1744L, 1745L, 1750L, 1751L, 1752L
), AverageTemperatureUncertainty = c(3.1304125, 3.0976671875, 
3.00175, 3.13747272727273, 3.09229285714285, 3.06561458333333
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @NelsonGon Just for reference is this the correct use of `dput`?

Comment: Yes.  Just copy and add the output to your question. What is `ma`? Got it!

Comment: @NelsonGon ma is the moving average function for 5 and 10 years respectively that I am trying to plot in the other to `geom_line`.

Comment: Try this: `Ma <- ma(df$AverageTemperatureUncertainty, order = 5)
Ma2 <- ma(df$AverageTemperatureUncertainty, order = 2)
mas<-data.frame(Ma=Ma,Ma2=Ma2)
df1<-cbind(df,mas)
df1 %>% 
  gather("id","value",2:ncol(.)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(dt,value,col=id))+geom_line()+scale_y_log10()`

Comment: @NelsonGon, throws the error `Error: unexpected symbol in "df1<-cbind(temp,mas) df1"`

Comment: place on different lines

Comment: @NelsonGon Yes. I made breaks where putting into new variables.

Comment: @NelsonGon Nearly worked, apart from it has managed to include `AverageTemperatureUncertainty` which I do not wish to include.

Comment: Your provided data includes that column only. There was no average temperature

Comment: @NelsonGon Apologies, I must have used `dput` incorrectly. There are only 3 columns, `dt`, `AverageTemperature` and `AverageTemperatureUncertainty`. I only want `AverageTemperature` on the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors you're getting are mostly due to what is inside and outside the `aes` brackets. These should contain all and only the values that vary for each data point:

- `Columns 'y', 'colour'` refers to your `y = ma` and `y = ma2` parts (and `color =` bits that follow). In your calls above it is looking inside the dataframe `temp` as defined in the first `ggplot` bracket and is unable to find these variables.
- You don't want the colour to vary by datapoint, so in each `geom_line` call take this out of the `aes()` bracket and set it as a constant colour.
- `size = 1.5` is also constant across variables in each `geom_line` call, so should be outside of `aes()`.
- `'mapping' must be created by 'aes()'` refers probably to both your `x = dt` part in the `ggplot` bracket (this should be in an `aes()` bracket as well), and the call of `temp` in each subsequent `geom_line` bracket.

It would be easier and tidier to calculate the moving averages and combine these into the original dataframe:

```
library(dyplr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1421)
ma <- function(x,order=5){stats::filter(x,rep(1/order,order), sides=2)}

temp<-tibble(AverageTemperature=rnorm(131, 10, 3), dt=seq(1870,2000))



ma1 <- ma(temp$AverageTemperature, order = 5)
ma2 <- ma(temp$AverageTemperature, order = 10)

temp$ma1 <- ma1
temp$ma2 <- ma2

ggplot(temp, aes(x = dt)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = AverageTemperature), color="orange", size = 1.5) + scale_y_log10() + xlim(1870, 2000) +
  geom_line(aes(y = ma1), color = "red", size = 1.5) +  
  geom_line(aes(y = ma2), color = "blue", size = 1.5)
```

Giving the graph (from randomly generated values):

[image: sample graph]

(I've created `ma` as a new function)

Does this help? You'll need to play around with colours etc. to suit.

Edit: actually seeing Nelson's code above which is handier for putting in the legend. Instead of the last `ggplot` command in my code above you could instead do:

```
temp %>% gather("id","value",c(1,3,4)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(dt,value,col=id))+
geom_line(size=1.5)+scale_y_log10() +
xlim(1870, 2000)
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing, very clear and concise explanations and fully understood what the errors mean. One problem is that the outlier at ~-3 degrees does not appear in my dataset when checking with `min(temp$AverageTemperature`. Do you know what could have introduced it?

Comment: That's my random data, it seems to like to throw a mad outlier in there for fun! Yours will likely look very different.

Comment: Glad you found help. Was away from my PC so couldn't take a look.

Comment: No problem! Just to note in my edited extra code at the bottom: 1) the `c(1,3,4)` part selects the three series of datapoints from the original dataframe, I've put them as the 1st, 3rd and 4th columns. Your order may be different. 2) This method puts the three data series in the same columns, distinguished by a new column `id`. The `col =` part now goes back into `aes()` as colour here **does** vary for each datapoint. Sorry if that's not clear!

Comment: @NelsonGon, Everything Running smoothly now, and graph looking exactly as meant to. Thanks both for helping a newcomer out!